# Downloading a JSON Array from a URL in Android

Tags: android, json, url, background, launch

I'm trying to download a JSON file in this format

[
  {
    "CRN":"10001",
    "Course":"REG1"
  },
  {
    "CRN":"10002",
    "Course":"REG2"
  }
]

I understand how to use a JSONArray class once it is created but I don't know how to create the JSONArray object from the file.  If the URL location of the file were to be "www.test.com" how would I go about downloading it in background upon the launch of my application so as to not interfere with the launching of the app but not require the user to manually download it themselves.

Comment: could you post your code ??

Comment: I don't have any. I have no clue what to do. I've googled this extensively and tried a bunch of different things but none have worked.

Comment: you need to download the json in background thread that's your issue  ??

Comment: Try using a Thread or an AsyncTask that launches when the application launches that does the job while the application is loading.

Comment: The most important aspect of this is that I download the data from the url into a JSONArray object. Once I accomplish that I'll do that task as an asynch task

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this helpful library:  [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

It makes grabbing and parsing JSON data easy!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for Android Web Service example. Where you can find info about

1.How to make a HTTP request to server (using URL eg. www.google.com)
2. How to handle Response from Server
3. How to parse JSON/XML response from Server etc.

Here is the Simple Tutorial I Found for you.

> [Android Web service for  Log-in and Registration](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Just go through step by step.

In the example we are making request to server for login and getting response then going ahead in app.

Here is the code snipp.

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);           
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to download the JSON file automatically, would be to launch an `AsyncTask` during your `onCreate` method of the home activity.

JSON files are nothing more than text files in a special format, so the could be easily downloaded as a response from a `HttpURLConnection`, and then be treated as a String.

A suggestion for parsing the JSON objets into Java objects would be the Jackson JSON Processor. You could use the class [ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html/) of this library to automatically create the objects.

If you are planing to implement the server side by yourself, and you also need a library to send JSON objects, you could use [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) on both server and client.